# SQL Server : Select statement with select case nested

Tags: sql-server

I have two tables

- Table 1, columns:  A, B, C
- Table 2, columns:  A, D, E

I want to select all from table 1 with an additional field added.

If the contents of string column table_1.A exists in table_2.A, then TRUE, if not then FALSE.

I'd love to tell you what I've tried, but nothing is coming close.  I can do this with a SELECT CASE statement, but I can't figure out how to select all at the same time.

Thanks

Comment: Do you mean that if text of Table1.A is anywhere in the text of Table2.A you want the word "TRUE" or you want something from Table2 included?

Comment: Yes, I don't need anything from table 2.  I've marked the answer that worked for me.  
Consider it like this:  table 1 = a list of products and table 2 = a list of inventory.  so this query would give a TRUE to anything in stock, and a FALSE to anything OUT of stock.  Hope that makes sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `CASE`

```
SELECT
    table1.A,
    table1.B,
    table1.C,
    CASE WHEN table2.A IS NULL THEN 'FALSE' ELSE 'TRUE' END
FROM
    table1
LEFT OUTER JOIN
    table2
ON  table1.A = table2.A
```

Comment: this could be close, but let me update the question.  It will never be null, it just wont exist..   so if table1.a not in table2.a then false..
I believe this query would always return TRUE, correct?

Comment: @stevo22: He knows table2.a will never be null - but his expression will be NULL if there is no match. I'm doing the same thing.

Comment: Great!!  Let me give it a shot.

Comment: That seems to have done it..  I added an 'AS' after the CASE statement so I could effectively refer to in code..  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT T1.*, IIF(T2.D IS NULL, 'FALSE', 'TRUE')
  FROM Table1 T1
  LEFT JOIN Table2 T2 ON T2.A LIKE '%' + T1.A + '%'
```

Comment: This also accomplished what I wanted, but it took substantially longer.  I assume its because of the LIKE.  (dealing with a lot of data here).   Thank you for your answer

Answer (score 0):

You need a left outer join and them compare both tables using the case when columnab is not null then true else false

Answer (score 0):

This would give you only one row per record in Table1.

```
SELECT  Table1.*, 
        ISNULL([Found],'False') [Found]
FROM    Table1
        OUTER APPLY (
            SELECT TOP 1
                    'True' AS [Found]
            FROM    Table2
            WHERE   Table2.A LIKE '%' + Table1.A + '%'
        )
```